# Rails's PUT request via link_to becomes POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

In views file, my code is similar with:

```
<%= link_to refresh_post_user_post_path(@user,@post), :method => :put%>
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put :refresh_post
    end
  end
end
```

The interesting thing is when inspecting the request object in controller:

```
def refresh_post
  ... ...
  p request.method # => POST
  p request.request_method # => PUT
  ... ...
end
```

I know method and request method are different, but where's POST request from?

Moreover:

```
$ rake routes 
refresh_post_user_post_path PUT /users/:user_id/posts/:id/refresh_post, {:action => "refresh_post", :controller => "posts"}
```

I am with Rails 3.0.11 and Ruby ree-1.8.7, everything above works with no exception. But any body knows how come the request is a POST?

Answer (score 3):

Rails emulates "advanced" request types (PUT, DELETE, etc) with a POST type. This is because browsers typically support only GET and POST.

So rails accepts a POST request and looks for a `:method` parameter. If such parameter is found, it updates request type accordingly (so that your routes can work, for example).

Comment: That makes sense. But if in a Update method of a resource controller, request.method will be PUT rather than POST I think

Comment: I haven't checked that yet. Could you verify?

Comment: Regardless, the web browser sees it as a POST request.

Comment: Thanks both, I find my answer as below

Answer (score 0):

The truth is request.method always returns POST, no matter for a PUT or POST request and no matter the controller method is a default 'update' or a custom one. Sergio, you are right.
It is from Rails' doc for request class:

**method**:
Returns the original value of the environment’s REQUEST_METHOD, even if it was overridden by middleware

**request_method**:
Returns the HTTP method that the application should see. In the case where the method was overridden by a middleware (for instance, if a HEAD request was converted to a #GET, or if a _method parameter was used to determine the method the application should use), this method returns the overridden value, not the original.

The interesting thing is even if it is a PUT request, in the log file it says like:

```
Started POST "/users/251/posts/1234" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jan 18 21:48:21 +0800 2012
```

This happens in Rails 3.0.11, and log file doesn't tell it is a PUT request at all. However in later versions, it has been fixed:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/17a91a6ef93008170e50c073d1c3794f038a0a33

And the log becomes as friendly as:

```
Started PUT "/users/251/posts/1234" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Jan 18 21:48:21 +0800 2012
```